# How to refresh stop-words list without restart postgres server?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have custom search configuration with stop-words. What I need to do to make the postgres server see the changes in the list of stop-words?

**upd 1**

I created file `russian_extended.stop` in catalog `pg10\share\postgresql\tsearch_data`.

Then I executed commands

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY public.russian_extended (
        TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple,
        STOPWORDS = russian_extended
    );
```

and then

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.russian_extended (
        COPY = pg_catalog.russian
    );
```

and in the end

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.russian_extended
        ALTER MAPPING
            FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart, hword, hword_part, word
            WITH russian_extended;
```

**upd 2**

After that I add a new word to the list and I don't understand how to apply this changes on the fly without restart my postgres server ...

Comment: What is the type of the dictionary that uses the stop word list?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I completed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the solution in the official [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-altertsdictionary.html), my fail was that I put into the list result of function `to_tsvector`

```sql
ALTER TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY public.russian_extended (StopWords=russian_extended);
```

Comment: It also mentions `ALTER TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY my_dict ( dummy );` - to re-read configs without having to restate your dictionary's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the source, a text search dictionary is initialized whenever the dictionary is first used, or after a cache invalidation (function `lookup_ts_dictionary_cache`).

So just starting a new database session should make changes in the stopword file active.

I did not verify if that is the case, can you test?

If you have any full text search indexes using a configuration with a dictionary where you changed the stopword file, you'll have to rebuild these indexes.

Comment: Yes, thank you for answer, I am refreshing my search index by the request from service